# Bresenham Algorithm "TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, pandas, bresenham

I'm trying to implement the bresenham algorithm. I have raster data and an observer point that I have chosen on the raster. I created a buffer around the observer point from raster data. I know the coordinates of the points inside the buffer and on the buffer. What I want is to create a line between the observer point and the points in the buffer using the bresenham algorithm and compare the heights of the points. To understand where the observer can and cannot see according to this comparison.

But I got a type error while running the algorithm. Can you help me? I am sharing the code I am using.

I exported the raster data via qgis and saved it as csv. I did the same for the observer point.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from rasterio.plot import show
import gdal

ds = pd.read_csv("aster_latlon.csv")
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(ds.longitude, ds.latitude)]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:32620'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ds, geometry = geometry, crs = crs)

obs = pd.read_csv("observerpoint.csv")
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(obs.longitude, obs.latitude)]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:32620'}
obsGdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(obs, geometry = geometry, crs = crs)

buffer = gdf.geometry[72477].buffer(0.08)
selected = gdf.intersects(buffer)
ds["Selected"] = selected 

x,y = buffer.exterior.xy 
l = x,y

lat = list(l[1])
long = list(l[0])

def bresenham(x1,y1,x2, y2):
 
    m_new = 2 * (y2 - y1)
    slope_error_new = m_new - (x2 - x1)
 
    y=y1
    for x in range(x1,x2+1):
     
        print("(",x ,",",y ,")\n")
 
        # Add slope to increment angle formed
        slope_error_new =slope_error_new + m_new
 
        # Slope error reached limit, time to
        # increment y and update slope error.
        if (slope_error_new >= 0):
            y=y+1
            slope_error_new =slope_error_new - 2 * (x2 - x1)
         
     
 
 
# driver function
if __name__=='__main__':
    
    x1 = obs['latitude']
    y1 = obs['longitude']

    for i in range(len(lat)):
        x2 = lat[i]
        y2 = long[i]
    
    bresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Here traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last) in module

> for x in range(x1,x2+1)

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Here traceback:                                                                                                  
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-9b21b6f4e00a> in <module>
     37 #     y2 = y2.astype(int, errors = 'ignore')
     38 
---> 39     bresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2)

<ipython-input-70-9b21b6f4e00a> in bresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2)
      5 
      6     y=y1
----> 7     for x in range(x1,x2+1):
      8 
      9         print("(",x ,",",y ,")\n")

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @CerenAşkit You can edit your question to include the traceback there, as writing it in a comment, as you can see, is not very legible (comments cannot contain multi-line formatted text).

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you're trying to do.  In the `__main__` block you have a for loop assigning `x2` and `y2` for each element in a pair of lists, but then you call `bresenham` only once.  I'm not sure what you intend the arguments `x1` and `y1`, but you are passing them an entire column of values from a DataFrame, as opposed to individual scalar values..

Comment: x1 and y1 relating to the observer point. The points x2 and y2 in the for loop are the points on the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not necessarily with your `bresenham` function itself (though to make it actually useful I would modify it to actually *return* a value and not just print).

The problem is how you're calling it:

```
    
    x1 = obs['latitude']
    y1 = obs['longitude']

    for i in range(len(lat)):
        x2 = lat[i]
        y2 = long[i]
    
    bresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Here `x1` is an entire column from a Pandas DataFrame also known as a `Series` object.  You did `x1 = obs['latitude']` and likewise for `y1`.  Then you are passing it as the first argument to `range()` which expects an integer, not a `Series`, hence the error message.

I don't know what you meant to do here.  Your for loop also makes no sense because you're effectively just assigning `x2 = lat[-1]` and `y2 = long[-1]`.